# Euler function and least common multiple

Tags: totient-function, least-common-multiple

Could you give me hint, what is the relationship between the $\phi$ and the $lcm$ functions? In the sense, that:
$p$, $q$ are primes s.t. $m < pq$ and

$$ m^{lcm(p-1, q-1)+1} \equiv m \mod pq $$

So what happens, is that we take out the gcd from $\phi{(pq)}$

What is the reason for this, that the equation works?

Comment: You don't take out the gcd from $\phi{(pq)}$, for $\phi{(pq)}$ is just a number; what use is it to take a gcd of **one** number?

Comment: Yeah maybe i was a bit loosy about it. I meant, that phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1) and lcm(p-1, q-1) = ((p-1)(q-1))/gcd(p-1, q-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) $m^p\equiv m \mod p$, ans so is $m^{x(p-1)+1}$ for any integer $x$. Also, $m^{y(q-1)+1}\equiv m \mod q$. Since $lcm(p-1,q-1)$ is divisible both by $p-1$ and $q-1$, $m^{lcm(p-1,q-1)+1}$ satisfies both of these conditions, so...

Comment: i tried to derive it from euler, but I should have done it simply from the question how to get the first exponent for two primes, to satisfiy the equation. Thanks for the hint!